# Overriding toString() in D class

Tags: class, d, tostring

I'm trying to override the toString method inside a class in the D language.

```
    override string toString() {
        auto a = to!string(a);
        auto b = to!string(b);

        return "%s / %s", a, b;
    }
```

I'm then creating an object called foo inside main() and then doing:

```
    writeln(foo);
```

Assuming a = 1 and b = 2, I want to get this string literal printed out:

```
    1 / 2
```

Instead, I only get the last number printed out

```
   2
```

I'm assuming string formatting doesn't work this way when returning.

Comment: I'm curious - why do you expect the comma operator to create a format string? I don't know of any language where that works.

Answer (score 11):

Wow. I've never seen anyone try that. No, that's not going to work. `toString` is like any other function that returns a `string`. There's nothing special about it except that some library functions (such as `format` and `writeln`) know to call it in order to convert an object to a `string`. So, you'd get exactly the same behavior if you did

```
string convToString(Foo foo)
{
    auto a = to!string(foo.a);
    auto b = to!string(foo.b);

    return "%s / %s", a, b;
}
```

and then did

```
writeln(convToString(foo));
```

But what's biting you here is the comma operator. When it runs,

```
return "%s / %s", a, b;
```

is going to become

```
return "%s / %s", "1", "2";
```

and the result of the comma operator is its last argument, so `"2"` gets returned. And since `"%s / %s"`, and `"1"` have no side effects, they're pretty much pointless. At that point, you might as well have just written

```
return b;
```

rather than

```
return "%s / %s", a, b;
```

What you *want* to do is to use [`std.string.format`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_string.html#format). and change your `toString` function to

```
override string toString()
{
    return format("%s / %s", a, b);
}
```

`format` will then create the `string` that you want.

On a side note, naming a local variable the same as a member variable as you did in your example is pretty much just asking for bugs, since it becomes easy to confuse the local variables and the member variables at that point.

Comment: Thanks, I also figured out you can use ~ to concatenate

Comment: @PhilKurtis Yes, but that's less efficient if you're building a string from a variety of different variables rather than just combining a couple of strings - especially if you have to convert some of the variables to strings first.